# Adding the uses-sdk fields in Androids manifest file causes crash

Tags: android, android-manifest

For some reason, when adding the uses-sdk fields in Android's manifest file causes crash. I've not had this happen before but I can't get rid of it now.

The relevant portion of the manifest file is as follows:

```
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
```

moving the permission line above, or below the uses-sdk clause makes no difference, nor does changing the minimum or target version. No matter what is selected (within reason because I can't go back to API 8, or 10, or any really early level) the application crashes if the uses-sdk clause is in the file.

Removing it allows it to run.

The error I get is the "unfortunately [app] has stopped" default and there's an associated "FATAL EXCEPTION: main" error in the logcat listing.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you!

This is an example of a book I'm working through (or trying to I should say). :)

I'm adding the complete logcat listing below.

```
10-03 13:29:18.270: E/Trace(860): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-03 13:29:18.950: D/AndroidRuntime(860): Shutting down VM
10-03 13:29:18.950: W/dalvikvm(860): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.paad.earthquake/com.paad.earthquake.Earthquake}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:341)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:486)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at com.paad.earthquake.EarthquakeListFragment.refreshEarthquakes(EarthquakeListFragment.java:77)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at com.paad.earthquake.EarthquakeListFragment.onActivityCreated(EarthquakeListFragment.java:55)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:848)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1017)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1802)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5011)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
10-03 13:29:18.960: E/AndroidRuntime(860):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: It would help if you added the full error log. Removing uses-sdk is definitely not the way to go. You should always define your minimum version and your target version (typically the last one)

Comment: I've added the full listing from the logcat output. It's perplexing.  I've never had a problem with any previous example I've attempted, and I'm not sure why this is causing trouble on something so simple.

Answer (score 1):

The error is `NetworkOnMainThreadException`
Starting with ICS, you cannot do any network access on main thread. You should probably use 
`AsyncTask` where you do network access.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it, but I did try a quick and dirty way to get around that before. I started a new thread          `Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    
    call () to do Some Stuff here;
   }
  });
  
  t.start();`

Comment: I guess I'm also wondering if Async Task is right for this application or if I should be using a service instead..

Comment: Beware, doing something in a service does not mean doing it on a background thread. All components of Android app use the same (main/GUI) thread by default. Even if you create a service, you would have to create a separate thread for your network access.

Comment: (or explicitly declare that the service has to run on another thread)

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm still digging into a solution but your comments are appreciated. Will post the result as soon as I have this figured out.

Comment: I found my initial error. In a rookie mistake, I omitted the thread's runnable wrapper around a method. I agree that the processing should be in a Async or service wrapper, and I'll add that soon. At least it's running without crashing though, so that's progress. thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sameer said, you are doing network calls in the core of your Activity. You should NEVER do that. All the code of your activity run on the main thread : the one that is used for the UI.
You should not make any heavy calculation on that thread : it takes resources away from the UI, making it lag.
An http call is even worse : as long as you don't have the response the UI is blocked.

Implement your network calls in an AsyncTask.

Comment: thanks. Still learning. Will investigate Async Task and how to implement.

Comment: Found part of my problem (see response above). thanks again for your helpful suggestions.