# Why do I get exception when uses SDK version specified?

Tags: android, sdk, permissions

Why do I have to remove

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

to make

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

work?

If I leave both I get an exception when using a function that tries to get access to the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've refrained from giving us a stack trace, I'm giving this answer with a bit of guessing.

My guess is you're getting a [`NetworkOnMainThreadException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). This exception occurs on Android 3.0 and above, when you try to use the network on the main UI thread. when you add the `<uses-sdk>` tag to your app, you build your app against API 16, which is higher than Honeycomb. This also explains why you don't see the exception on Gingerbread.

To fix this, move all networking code into a [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) or an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: I've got Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception NetworkOnMainThreadException)). "move all networking code into a Thread or an AsyncTask." - Could you explain how to do that - I'm a newbie :)

Comment: Start here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html

Answer (score -1):

That is not correct. You need not remove the

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Make sure the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

is placed after the

```
<uses-sdk>
```

tag and before the

```
<application>
```

tag.

You could also refer to [Adding the uses-sdk fields in Androids manifest file causes crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712630/adding-the-uses-sdk-fields-in-androids-manifest-file-causes-crash)

Comment: The uses-sdk tag is entirely optional and can be safely removed in most cases during development. Google Play might not let you upload the app without one, but it is possible to write, compile and run an app without it.