# App crashes on startup when using <uses-sdk> in manifest

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-manifest, viewflipper

I have implemented `ViewFlipper` which runs fine when I do **not** use the `<uses-sdk>` lines in manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.warde.loyal"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

The exception is generated in `setContentView`. See the logging

```
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851): Process: com.warde.loyal, PID: 3851
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.warde.loyal/com.warde.loyal.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:340)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1973)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at com.warde.loyal.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     ... 11 more
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     ... 26 more
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:677)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:507)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:872)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3054)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:133)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:123)
02-17 10:23:59.479: E/AndroidRuntime(3851):     ... 29 more
```

This is my code that implemented `ViewFlipper`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
private ViewFlipper mViewFlipper;   
private AnimationListener mAnimationListener;
private Context mContext;


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private final GestureDetector detector = new GestureDetector(new SwipeGestureDetector());

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mContext = this;
    mViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) this.findViewById(R.id.view_flipper);
    mViewFlipper.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {
            detector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });


            mViewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
            mViewFlipper.setFlipInterval(4000);
            mViewFlipper.startFlipping();

    //animation listener
    mAnimationListener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            //animation started event
        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            //TODO animation stopped event
        }
    };
}


class SwipeGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        try {
            // right to left swipe
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.left_in));
                mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.left_out));
                // controlling animation
                mViewFlipper.getInAnimation().setAnimationListener(mAnimationListener);
                mViewFlipper.showNext();
                return true;
            } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.right_in));
                mViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,R.anim.right_out));
                // controlling animation
                mViewFlipper.getInAnimation().setAnimationListener(mAnimationListener);
                mViewFlipper.showPrevious();
                return true;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
}
```

I think, Perhaps I need to implement `AsynkTask` ?

What should be changed in the code. ?

Thanks in advance...

## EDIT

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/lightning" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/ImageTitle"
            android:text="@string/lightning" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/color_baloons" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/ImageTitle"
            android:text="@string/color_baloons" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/natural_wall" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/ImageTitle"
            android:text="@string/natural_wall" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ViewFlipper>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your xml layout file?

Comment: You should see this two thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712630/adding-the-uses-sdk-fields-in-androids-manifest-file-causes-crash?rq=1 & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512981/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-12-error-inflating-class

Comment: post your main.xml file

Comment: Added main.xml also, thanks. have a look

Comment: Can you remove the ImageView and Check?@VivekWarde

Comment: @Muthu After removing ImagView It works, But I need to set background of relativelayout , I tried using `android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
                    android:src="@drawable/lightning"` but nothing improved ! Then I used ` android:background="@drawable/lightning"` This crashed the app

Comment: Now the question is how to set the background

Comment: I think your images are little bit big. you need to use ImageSwitcher instead of ViewFliper. or you can use low resolution images on ViewFliper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I was using very big size images, By using the compressed small size images solved !